# Characteristic function of $\exp(X)$ given characteristic function of $X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence, characteristic-functions

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199667/square-root-of-normal-distribution) on mathoverflow asks if normal distribution can be expressed as product of two i.i.d. variables, which is answered in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09838) in more general setting. The paper shows, that **if** $W_1, W_2, \ldots W_k$ are i.i.d. with distribution $$
W_1 \overset D = \varepsilon \exp \left(C - \sum_{m=0}^\infty \tilde G_{1/k, 1/(2m + 1)}\right)
$$
where $\varepsilon$ is Rademacher variable, $C$ is some appropriate constant, $\tilde G_{a, b}$ is gamma distribution shifted to have null expectation with shape $a$ and scale $b$, and $G$'s and $\varepsilon$ being independent, **then** $W_1 W_2 \ldots W_k \overset D = \mathcal N (0,1)$. It manages to do so with the help of exp-normal distribution, which is $\ln | \mathcal N (0, 1)|$.

I want to find characteristic function of $W_1$. So far I maneged to get charasteristic function of $\ln |W_1|$ (the inside of the $\exp$ function) which is $$\mathrm e^{itD}\sqrt[k]{\prod_{m=0}^\infty\frac 1 {1 + \frac t {2m + 1}}}$$ for some constant $D$.

Is there a way to get the characteristic function of $\exp (\ln | W_1|)$ from that? Or perhaps some different approach is needed?

---

**Update:** I tried plugging inverse transform formula for density function $$
f(x) = \int_{\mathbb R}\mathrm e^{-ixs} \varphi(s)\operatorname{d}\!s $$ into definition of characteristic function and got
\begin{align}
\varphi_{|W_1|}(t) &= \int_{\mathbb R}\exp(it\mathrm e^x) \left(\int_{\mathbb R}\mathrm e^{-ixs} \varphi_{\ln|W_1|}(s)\operatorname{d}\!s\right) \operatorname{d}\!x \\
& \overset ? =
\int_{\mathbb R} \varphi_{\ln|W_1|}(s) \left(\int_{\mathbb R}\exp(it\mathrm e^x-ixs)\operatorname{d}\!x\right) \operatorname{d}\!s.
\end{align}
I didn't bother checking Fubini's theorem assumptions in (?), because Wolfram said that inner integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, and when I tried to express it as some series I failed to produce anything meaningful.